# I would like to build a code that checks my imported mail in Gmail in Google Apps Script, how do I find this function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, google-schemas

As you might know, Gmail has the feature to check other email accounts (using pop3). I am using this feature a lot, but the annoying thing is it only checks the email once every 50 minutes of you have to do this manually in the settings, and the settings aren't available on mobile.
I would like to build something to check this mail automatically every minute. The best would be a Google Apps Script, because it is linked with Gmail and it can automatically run from the cloud every minute. The only problem is that I don't know how to make a javascript that automatically does the 'get mail now' feature. How would I build this?

Answer (score 0):

Google Script cannot be used for checking emails of other Google accounts.